# How can I copy the problem message of a currently selected line with a hotkey in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example as in the image below, I want to press a hotkey and the error (`expected value, found..` in this case) will be copied to my clipboard.

[image: example]

Comment: you can try to do it from the PROBLEMS panel

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are looking for currently exists.

There is a way to copy the problem message from the currently selected item in the Problems *Panel*, which is to bind a keyboard shortcut to the `problems.action.copyMessage` command.

To get what you're actually looking for, I think you'll need to [make a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md).

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/181227

added PR, hope they add it

if anyone is interested in this too, please upvote it